# Awesomium 1.7RC2 with VS11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, awesomium

I have a little problem and I dont know how to solve it (sadly).

I want to compile a sample project of the Awesomium 1.7RC2 SDK, it works fine with vs10, but with vs11 I do get some Errors.

These are the errors:

```
http://pastebin.com/6RdUffve
```

They are caused by these lines of code:

```
method_dispatcher_.Bind(app_object,
WSLit("SayHello"),
&Application::OnSayHello);
method_dispatcher_.Bind(app_object,
WSLit("Exit"),
&Application::OnExit);

method_dispatcher_.BindWithRetval(app_object,
WSLit("GetSecretMessage"),
&Application::OnGetSecretMessage);
```

The code of the dispatcher class:

header: http://pastebin.com/ktTEuQ4T

source: http://pastebin.com/FTDHQzJ9

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by a bug in VS2012, where std::function does not implicitly convert member function pointers to function pointers. This example, which should work according to Bjarne Stroustroups C++11 FAQ, throws the same error in my VS2012:

```
struct X {
    int foo(int);
};

function<int (X*, int)> f;
f = &X::foo;        // pointer to member

X x;
int v = f(&x, 5);   // call X::foo() for x with 5
```

You can work around this by creating static functions like

```
void StaticOnSayHello(Application* app, Awesomium::WebView* caller, const Awesomium::JSArray &args) {
    app->OnSayHello(caller, args);
}
```

etc, and giving these as the third argument to method_dispatcher::Bind.